# Implement Elasticsearch aggregation snd sort query using Java API and sort based on reversed

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch nested aggregation query(below), that I am trying to implement in Java using the Elasticsearch Java API. The query counts keywords and sorts using the reversed_nested _count. The query works in dev tools and partly Java, the only I can not sort using the Java API using the reversed_count.

```
GET products/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "affectedProducts.seller"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered_nestedobjects": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "affectedProducts.seller.onOrWith": false
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_products": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "affectedProducts.seller.vendor.keyword",
                "order": {
                  "reversed_count": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "reversed_count": {
                  "reverse_nested": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement using the java API to sort using reversed_count? I have tried using BucketOrder.count button working.

Please help.

Thanks

```
  public SearchRequest createSearchRequest() {
    final NestedAggregationBuilder vendor;
    vendor = nested("products_count", "affectedProducts.seller")
        .subAggregation(filter("running", termQuery("affectedProducts.seller.onOrWith", false))
            .subAggregation(terms("filter_products").field("affectedProducts.seller.vendor.keyword").order(BucketOrder.count(false)))
            .subAggregation(reverseNested("vendors_reverse")));

    return searchRequest("products")
        .aggregation(
            global(AGG)
                .subAggregation(vendor)
        )
//        .sort(new Sortable().setSort("_count"))
        .page(limitTo(0))
        .build();
  }
```

ES Version: 7.10.6

Comment: Are you using HLRC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is that the **reversed_count** subAggs must be subaggregation of **filter_products**.

```
   final NestedAggregationBuilder vendor;
    vendor = nested("products_count", "affectedProducts.seller")
        .subAggregation(filter("filtered_nestedobjects", termQuery("affectedProducts.seller.onOrWith", false))
            .subAggregation(terms("filter_products").field("affectedProducts.seller.vendor.keyword")
                .order(BucketOrder.aggregation("reversed_count", false))
                .subAggregation(reverseNested("reversed_count"))));

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("products");
    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(vendor);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Comment: Thanks @rabbitbr the reversed_count subAgg was in the wrong place.